# Microsoft SQL Server on LAN

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a little problem with connection to my SQL Server 2012 from other PCs in my domain at my local area network.

I already set the TCP/IP connection from this server right, and did create a user

```
csb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
csb.DataSource = "PC-81";
csb.UserID = "bla";
csb.Password = "bla";
csb.IntegratedSecurity = false;
csb.InitialCatalog = "CryptoChat";
```

So this is the connection string I built in C#, I have an SQLProperty that updates my controls on the user interface. SQL Server constantly tries to login with the domain account, but I turned that off. Can you help me? I have totally no idea why its not working

Greetings Markus

this is the code which sets up the `SqlConnection`:

```
if (conn == null)
{
    conn = new SqlConnection(csb.ConnectionString);
}

if (cmdUser == null)
{
   cmdUser = new SqlCommand(SQLSTRUser, conn);
}
```

`SQLSTRUser` ist the `SELECT` command for my database

Here is the exception I get:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Die von der Anmeldung angeforderte CryptoChat-Datenbank kann nicht geöffnet werden. Fehler bei der Anmeldung.
>   Fehler bei der Anmeldung für den Benutzer '*DomainUser*'.

Which according to Google Tranlate means:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Requested by the CryptoChat application database can not be opened. The login failed. Login failed for user 'Domain User'.

Comment: How do you know that it is using domain/windows account to logon?

Comment: i looked in the further information on the Exception it said "cant login through <domainname>/<user>

Comment: Obviously the connection string you have build is not being used to open connection. Can you share the codes where you set connection string?  and  getting the exception?

Comment: OK the Exception is on German, and its a text, because ill try it on a PC without Visual Studio

Comment: nhrobin u were right about it. i looked the logs from the SQL Server, and they say its only try to connect from Domain Accounts..

Comment: Your Sql Server only accepts Windows Authentication. You need to change it allow both Windows and Sql Server authintication.

Comment: http://666kb.com/i/cgeitx9l0psyliqo2.png Yeah, i tried this first.. but still same problem

Comment: @Ethnor Did you also restart your SQL Server?  This is required when you change the authentication setting.  If so, then what is the new error message that you are getting?

Comment: :( I did this, because the server said so, right click onto the server and restart.. Didnt change the error message. But thanks, could it be..

Comment: Wait, it still says "Login failed for '***Domain User***'"."?!?

Comment: i wrote it cause its a domain name from my work and my workmate's Domain Account, shoulda write that too sorry

Comment: No, my question is, is it still showing the *Domain Name* or does it now show the *SQL Login name* in the error message?

Comment: Ah okay, misunderstood. It's the Domain Name showing up in the error Message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your responses in the comments, I think that this can be reduced to one of two possibilities.  Either:

1. Your code is not connecting to the Server that you think it is (i.e., not the same one that you changed the authentication setting on), or it's not using the connection settings that you think it is or
2. You have a security policy in place that is preventing you from changing SQL Server to Mixed Authentication.

The first one above is more likely and much more common than most developers realize.  To test this, have it print out the connection string/information on the line before it connects.

Comment: I did printout it, and it seems correct. Now i should be looking for Security Policies. I tried different rules of the server, currently i am using sa that should having the rights.. What do i look after? a Security Settings which says "dont connect as a user"? €: I am very thankful for your help everyone!

Comment: Use SQL Profiler to trace the SQL Server while your program attempts to connect. Be sure to include all Audit Login and Error events in the trace, as well as all of the login/user info columns. Look for the LogFail event from your program and let us know what information it has.

Comment: Sometimes its the simple thing, it didnt connect cause i used the debug directory and not my release directory to test. So the Connection does work at all

Comment: @Ethnor So that was #1, correct?  Like I said, it's a lot more common than most developers realize.  I suspect it's because unlike SQL Server tools, program code usually has no visual indicator of what it's really trying to connect to.

Comment: I started my tool out of the debug Directory and i released it to the release directory. So i started  the wrong